# Extract data out of an object array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array and can't figure out how to get the data out:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => stdClass Object ( 
      [address_components] => Array ( 
         [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [long_name] => 180 
            [short_name] => 180 
            [types] => Array ( [0] => street_number ) 
         ) 
         [1] => stdClass Object ( 
            [long_name] => Campus Dr 
            [short_name] => Campus Dr 
            [types] => Array ( [0] => route ) 
         ) 
         [2] => stdClass Object ( 
            [long_name] => Arcadia 
            [short_name] => Arcadia 
            [types] => Array ( 
               [0] => locality 
               [1] => political 
            ) 
         ) 
         [3] => stdClass Object ( 
            [long_name] => Los Angeles 
            [short_name] => Los Angeles 
            [types] => Array ( 
               [0] => administrative_area_level_2 
               [1] => political 
            )
         ) 
         [4] => stdClass Object ( 
            [long_name] => California 
            [short_name] => CA 
            [types] => Array ( 
               [0] => administrative_area_level_1 
               [1] => political 
            ) 
         ) 
         [5] => stdClass Object ( 
            [long_name] => United States 
            [short_name] => US 
            [types] => Array ( 
               [0] => country 
               [1] => political 
            ) 
         ) 
         [6] => stdClass Object ( 
            [long_name] => 91007 
            [short_name] => 91007 
            [types] => Array ( [0] => postal_code ) 
         ) 
      ) 
      [formatted_address] => 180 Campus Dr, Arcadia, CA 91007, USA 
      [geometry] => stdClass Object ( 
         [location] => stdClass Object ( 
            [lat] => 34.1301857 
            [lng] => -118.0333596 
         ) 
         [location_type] => ROOFTOP 
         [viewport] => stdClass Object ( 
            [northeast] => stdClass Object ( 
               [lat] => 34.131534680292 
               [lng] => -118.03201061971 
            ) 
            [southwest] => stdClass Object ( 
               [lat] => 34.128836719709 
               [lng] => -118.03470858029 
            ) 
         ) 
      ) 
      [partial_match] => 1 
      [types] => Array ( [0] => street_address ) 
   ) 
)
```

This is stored in a variable called `$results`

EDIT:
Although this has already been answered, (thank you), this is what I was attempting:

```
foreach($results as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

And it was throwing an error: `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

I knew I was accessing it incorrectly but just couldn't remember what I was doing wrong.

Comment: What do you want to access? You might want to have a look at http://ch2.php.net/oop5

Comment: Also, it would be helfpul if you posted the formatted version of your output.

Comment: Have you tried, what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Imran: Call it a brain freeze. I was accessing it as a string array and it was failing. Couldn't remember how to access an object array, did a google search and couldn't find anything helpful, so I posted here. Sorry if my question has offended you?

Comment: @kylex i humbly beg pardon if my comments (which are removed) were in any way offensive to you. Me as part of stack-overflow community just wish to keep it running  in good shape.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo $results[0]->address_components[0]->long_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach( $results[0]->address_components as $id => $address )
{
   echo "\n$id. address: {$address->long_name}\n";
   foreach ( $address->types as $type )
   {
      echo $type , ' ';
   }
}
echo $results[0]->geometry->viewport->southwest->lat;
```

And, if it is something you get from `json_decode()` , then you should pay attention to the second parameter for that function. If `true`, it will create your good old array.